# invoke gradle in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use gradle in jenkins pipeline. The build fails with error "Task clean not found in root project 'pipe1'"

Installed jenkins on centos

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('source') {
            steps {
                git 'https://github.com/javahometech/my-app.git'
            }
        }
        stage('compile') {
            tools {
                gradle 'gradle3'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'gradle clean compile'
            }
        }
    }
}

build fails with error

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'clean' not found in

Comment: have you checked the gradle file is present in the location where the jenkins pipeline run ?.

Comment: I am not sure what gradle fie you are referring to ? is it build.gradle ? I am not sure where the file should be ? I am assuming you referring to the workspace folder of jenkins

Comment: I created build.gradle in the project folder with below entry "apply plugin 'java'" , still fails with same error

Comment: yes correct and from github link that you have added there isnt any build.gradle present there.

Comment: I created the build.gradle in the terminal manually. I also ran the gradle clean and compileJava manually in the terminal, it worked. But the jenkins build fails. In Global Tools config (in Jenkins), I have given the path for Gradle home /opt/gradle/gradle-3.4.1 (gradle is installed in this folder on node)